# C - expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before function arguments

Tags: c, typedef

My header has defined the following codes:

```
typedef uint8_t EnrollT(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void ChangeT(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *, ChangeT *);
```

I have implemented these two functions and pass those to ClientAlloc() in my c file as shown in the following:

```
ClientAlloc(Enroll, Change);
```

However, when I compile the source, the errors pops up.

```
expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘enroll’
expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘change’
```

Is there anything I may miss here?

For `EnrollT` and `ChangeT`, I declare it in my code:

```
uint8_t Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2){...};
void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2){...};
```

For `ClienAlloc`:

```
struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(Enroll, Change){... return something};
```

Comment: How did you declare `enroll` and `change` ?

Comment: Deleted my answer because although it's *likely* that you forgot a semicolon somewhere, nobody can really tell with this tiny bit of code. Please show a complete verifiable example of the problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and Felix,  I have updated my question.

Comment: I put together an example built from the snippets given in the question (although I removed the unnecessary trailing `;` after each function implementation) and the result was - *no compilation errors* (MSVC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to `ClientAlloc` function addresses of your `Enroll` and `Change` functions

Then your

```
struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(Enroll, Change){... return something}
```

must be

```
struct ClusterT *ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q){... return something}
```

An example code is:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t EnrollT(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void ChangeT(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);

struct ClusterT *ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q)
{
   return NULL;
}

uint8_t enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2)
{
    return 0;
}

void change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2)
{

}

int main(void) {

    ClientAlloc(enroll, change);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my case, ClientAlloc will be the function to be executed. I have no main here. Would you please modify the sample code?

Comment: @user3815726 To be executed by what? Abither function? Move the code `ClientAlloc(enroll, change)` whre you need it.

Comment: I mean ClientAlloc will like the main function here in my case.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm little bit confused. `struct ClusterT *ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q){..}` is the function. If you want to substitute main with that you cannot. Otherwise I'm not getting you.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine here:

```
typedef uint8_t EnrollT(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void ChangeT(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *, ChangeT *);


struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *x, ChangeT *y)
{
  (*x)(22,33);
  return NULL;
}


unsigned char enrollfunc(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2)
{
  return 123;
}

void main()
{
  EnrollT *x = enrollfunc;
  ChangeT *y = NULL;


  ClientAlloc(x, y);
}
```

Comment: In my case, ClientAlloc will be the function to be executed. I have no main here. Would you please modify the sample code?

Comment: @user3815726 why modify the code that compiles and works fine ? I'm not sure I understand.